# Parse: iOS app crash issue

Tags: ios, parsing

Today our app suddenly stopped working on iOS devices. Our debugging attempts shows that we get an exception inside the Parse library. We are using `library version 1.1.32` which we believe is the cause of the problem.

The issue started happening soon after we made some changes to our database, which we initially thought was the cause, but the problem continued after we reverted the changes. Since the error happens inside the library code we think it had something to do with us using an outdated library.

The error log we obtained is given below. We tried getting rid of all parse queries one by one on our splash screen to identify the problematic query, but we got the same error no matter what. Therefore, right now we are clueless as to what is the root cause of the problem.

`2013-11-22 12:05:58.478 AdWin[2609:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil`'

```
*** First throw call stack:

(0x3000cf4b 0x3a44d6af 0x2ff46c81 0x13eef5 0x13f65f 0x2868bb 0x3a930d1b 0x3a930d07 0x3a93778d 0x2ffd7819 0x2ffd60ed 0x2ff40c27 0x2ff40a0b 0x34c67283 0x327e4049 0xc21b9 0xc2140)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Here is the library line that throws the exception: 0x257912: b 0x2578ee ; __40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 342 at PFTask.m:33

Comment: you are trying to insert an empty, nil object into an array. so probably you are expecting to pass a non empty object to one of your library calls.

Comment: put breakpoint and see on what line it is crashing.at that line you are passing nil value.

Comment: As I explained below we can't add a breakpoint because the exception is thrown within the Parse binary library. Is there a way to obtain a full stack trace thrown within binary c++ libraries?

Comment: It turns out the issue was at a completely different part of the code than we originally though. I apologize for troubling you. Thank you very much again for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpley add a check before adding your object to array like

```
if(object)
[_objectsArray addObject:object];
```

Comment: The problem is that the exception is not thrown by our application code. We send an async query to the Parse library (which is a binary library) and the exception is thrown inside the library. Therefore, we cannot put a breakpoint to see what object is nil. We are also unable to identify which query is causing the exception. We commented our every single parse query (which were supposed to cause other problems) but we still get the same exception from the library.

Comment: can you please put that part of code here?